# Convert a Hex-String to a Hex-Color value in SCSS

Tags: css, json, sass, colors, libsass

I have stored a lot of colors in json-format. I use [rootbeer](https://github.com/gkatsev/rootbeer) via gulp to turn them into sass maps that can be processed by the scss:

```json
{ "blue": "33A2FF" }
```

to

```
$colors: ( "blue": "33A2FF" );
```

I can use the colors just fine with the `#{}` syntax, but as soon as any color-functions like `lightness()` are applied the compiler fails because the color-type is entirely gone.

Even working with `unquote()` will not allow sass to treat this as nothing else but a string, but it needs to be a color.

My question is if there is any way for me to force the compiler to treat this as a color instead? The alternative will be to omit all uses of the [built-in color functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color).

Alternatively I could rewrite all hey as rgb, with seperate values for r, g and b and then use the `rgb()` syntax to return them as color, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829863/sass-error-color-is-not-a-color-on-unquoted-string). But that would require a significant rework. So maybe anyone has an idea of how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found utilities that allow the processing of strings in a hex format to rgb(): https://github.com/KittyGiraudel/SassyJSON/tree/master/stylesheets/decode/helpers/color